# Why can't we change the order of statements in insertion sort's while loop?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

As shown below is the basic insertion sort algorithm taught at school. if you change the order of while loop parameters, it doesn't work.

```
public static int[] insertionSort(int[] A){
    for(int i =1; i<A.length;i++){
        int key = A[i];
        int j = i;
        while(j>0&&A[j-1]>key){
            A[j]=A[j-1];
            j--;
        }
        A[j]=key;
        }       
    return A;
}
```

After the change (Now the code wont work and it will give  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 expection):

```
public static int[] insertionSort(int[] A){
    for(int i =1; i<A.length;i++){
        int key = A[i];
        int j = i;
        while(A[j-1]>key&&j>0){
            A[j]=A[j-1];
            j--;
        }
        A[j]=key;
        }       
    return A;
}
```

If there any other way to implement the same algorithm so that the order of the conditional loop statements doesn't matter?

Comment: Why does the order matter to you?

Comment: It does matter when you are writing it by yourself without looking at the online solution. Then you will always need to consider "the order effect" in your code.

Comment: Why are you breaking  working code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of short-circuit evaluation.

If the first half of an `&&` is false, the second half will not be evaluated at all (since the result cannot possibly be true).
Therefore, you can write `j > 0 && A[j - 1]...`, and `A[j - 1]` will only be evaluated if `j > 0`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I kind of figured that out but what I want is another algorithm to implement the same logic with same time complexity.

Comment: @Junaid He answered the question you asked in the title.

Comment: To add to SLaks answer, you could add one extra element to the beginning of the array. So the actual elements are indxed starting from 1 and not 0. This should have the effect that you want. Moreover if the extra value is a very large negative number, you dont even need to check if j>1 in the while loop. (j>1 because array elements start at 1)

Answer (score -1):

You can improve the above code as follow. Now the while loop will never fail for `arr[-1]` condition as every time `j==-1` the loop will break out.

```java
public static void InsertionSort()
    int j, temp;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the size");
    int n = sc.nextInt(); 
    int arr[] = new int[n];
    System.out.println("enter the elements");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp = arr[i]; 
        j = i - 1;
        while (arr[j] > temp && j >= 0)
        {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
            if (j == -1)
                break;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
    }
    System.out.println("Array Sorted through Insertion Sort");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```